# Verifying data that is encrypted in the browser

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

We have a file upload system that PGP encrypts data in the browser before it is sent to our servers. The files are then viewed by us in a specially designed local program. We decided this was the safest way to store that data. One downside to this we find in our own testing  is that we can really upload anything at all, random strings etc., because we can't verify what that data is once encrypted without keeping our private keys on a server that is connected to the internet. It seems to me that this is a pretty big potential flaw, though I can't put my finger on exactly what could be done with it. Aside from sanitizing and checking data before viewing it, what can we do to mitigate the issue? Should we take another route entirely for protecting the data?

Edit: We realized the public key used to encrypt could simply be changed by an attacker and they'd have access to all files encrypted from that point. The current suggestion is to encrypt using hashed user password+salt generated at login time and then storing that key on another server (protected by master password) so that we too can view them. The issue of changing keys seems to be mitigated by this (though keys could plausibly be intercepted while being sent to the secure storage server).

Comment: Please post your code and what have you tried so far

Comment: I can't provide code, but this is more an issue of the process rather than the specific code anyway to my mind

Comment: What's wrong with https?

Comment: Nothing, we use it in addition to this. We wanted these files to be stored with encryption in case of some kind of breach so they are useless to attackers (They will be things such as passport scans). We felt extending the encryption to the client side would prevent potential for a third party to intercept the unencrypted files on our servers.